# Setting Content-Security-Policy in JHipster

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, content-security-policy

I have 2 JHipster Spring Boot Apps. In dev A runs on localhost:8083 and B on localhost:8080.

In app A I have added an API Controller, which works fine when triggered from Postman.

From app B, when an Angular form calls the endpoint, I am seeing:

```
polyfills.1266a5de5d4c3910.js:1 Refused to connect to 'http://www.localhost:8083/MYURL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

In SecurityConfiguration.java there is:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

where I replaced:

```
   http
      .and()
          .headers() 
         .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
```

with

```
    http
      .and()
          .headers() 
          .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src *; connect-src *")
```

but it gives the same error.

I am thinking my code is explicitly setting both 'connect-src' and 'default-src' to accept anything - but no. Is this the right strategy? What am I missing?

Meta data:

- JHipster: v7.9.3
- Chrome cache cleared
- Java 11
- Windows 11

Comment: Why would an API call require a javascript resource? Your angular form in app A should request only JSON from app B where content-src is not applied like in Postman. So, I guess something is wrong in your form and should be fixed before thinking about CSP. Did you check that request content type is JSON?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Gael - it would never have occurred that not setting content type to JSON would throw  "violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". But now I believe I am seeing https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/20987 as the error is now " blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: Great. Once you get a fix, you should write an answer here to help others.

Comment: Your very thoughtful Gael, thanks. I got "Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check" error because in application.yml I uncommented the cors lines to allow cross origin. Not wanting to limit the origins I put "*" in allowed-origines rather than "http......". * is not allowed by Spring Boot, but it did not complain and somehow thats the error I saw.

Comment: Another issue I did not know I did not know - if the 2 apps are in Docker containers in the same network then I am thinking they communicate through the Docker network, not the client localhost. So the connect-src cant be localhost but something about the Docker network source. Am looking to push these issues into a Nginx container.

Comment: It depends on so many things: how you configure container's  network mode, whether you run on linux or windows, .... https://docs.docker.com/network/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have multiple Content Security Policies defined. Check your response headers and meta tags. You likely have a default policy "default-src 'self'" set by a framework or webserver that you need to disable or modify. Adding another policy can only make it stricter.